# Help restore file

Tags: editors

I'm in panic! Help restore the file. I write my graduation paper in Latex. I pressed the "Run" button. And my laptop turned off (the cord disconnected). Now I open file .tex, and it's empty!

Comment: Well, if there's no backup file made by the editor you're using the sad news is that your file is lost, most likely. Why don't you make backup files? It's a well-known fact that computers may fail and storing files at least twice on different disks is a 'must', especially for such important documents like thesis

Comment: I have a backup file, but there's a small part. I did a lot yesterday and today. I have not had time to save.

Comment: Check for a backup file first. Let me guess: you are using Windows. Let me also guess, somewhat less confidently: you are using Texmaker.

Comment: Note that 'I have not had time to save.' makes little sense. So you had time to lose the work? But a good editor will automatically make backups. If your editor doesn't do this *reliably*, find another editor.

Comment: Which editor do you have?